# Graphene resolver return function

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have created an ObjectType using Python Graphene however in the query object to return the data, I don't know what the return should be from the resolver.

My code is below:

```
class RunLog(ObjectType):
    status = String()
    result = String()
    log = List(String)

    def resolve_status(self, resolve, run_id):
        return r.hget("run:%i" % run_id, "status").decode('utf-8')

    def resolve_result(self, resolve, run_id):
        return r.hget("run:%i" % run_id, "result").decode('utf-8')

    def resolve_log(self, resolve, run_id):
        log_data = r.lrange("run:%i:log" % run_id, 0, -1)
        log_data = [entry.decode('utf-8') for entry in log_data]

        return log_data


class Query(ObjectType):
    log_by_run_id = Field(RunLog, run_id=Int(required=True))

    def resolve_log_by_run_id(root, info, run_id):
        return ???
```

The RunLog object should read from a redis database and return the data at the relevant run_id.

I want to be able to execute the following query to get the data associated with that run:

```
{
  logByRunId(runId: 1) {
    status
    result
    log
  }
}
```

What should the return be from 'resolve_log_by_run_id'? The Graphene documentation is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning a `RunLog` object, i.e.

```
def resolve_log_by_run_id(root, info, run_id):
    # fetch values from Redis here using run_id (status, result, log)
    run_log = RunLog(status=status, result=result, log=log)
    return run_log
```

Also, since the arguments passed to your method are named, you should consider renaming your method something less restrictive like `resolve_log` or `resolve_run_log`.  If you need to add another filter to your resolver, you won't need to add another method.